# Problem based on amplitude of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If the expression $(1 + ir)^3$
 is of the form of $s(1 + i)$ for some real $s$ where $r$ is also real and 
then the value of $r$ can be

$(A) \cot{\frac{\pi}{8}}$
$(B) \tan{\frac{\pi}{12}}$
$(C) \tan{\frac{5\pi}{8}}$
$(D) \sec{\pi}$

Since real and imaginary parts of the given complex number should be same.
So I put $3\tan^{-1}(r)=\pi/4$
I'm only getting (B) as an answer but according to my book (B),(C),(D) are all correct options.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: There is no answer (D) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of $(1+ir)^3$ is $3$ times that of $1+ir$, which is known to be one of $\pi/4$, $5\pi/4$. Then $$\arctan(r)=\frac\pi{12},\frac{9\pi}{12},\frac{17\pi}{12},\frac{5\pi}{12},\frac{13\pi}{12},\frac{21\pi}{12}.$$

Comment: Wait wait...I don't get you.The solutions should be $3\tan^{-1}(r)=\pi/4+2\pi n$ right?

Comment: @ZOZ: $s$ can be negative.

Comment: Oh silly me.I get it now!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$1-3r^2+i(3r-r^3)=s(1+i)$$

$$\implies3r-r^3=1-3r^2$$

If $r=\tan A\implies\tan3A=\dfrac{3r-r^3}{1-3r^2}=1\implies3A=m\pi+\dfrac\pi4=(4m+1)\dfrac\pi4$ where $m$ is any integer

$A=(4m+1)\dfrac\pi{12}$ where $m\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$

Comment: Nice...but can you tell me the mistake in my method?Why is my method not giving all the solutions?

Comment: @ZOZ, (Sanchayan) You are taking the principal root only.

Comment: So what should be the correct condition in place of $3\tan^{-1}|r|=\pi/4$ ?

Comment: Eh!You revealed my pseudonym :-P

Comment: @ZOZ, I was searching for my solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817300/how-to-integrate-frac-cos-7x-cos-8x12-cos-5x  remembering your name. Then Google helped me

Comment: @ZOZ, Yes, $3\tan^{-1}r=n\pi+\dfrac\pi4$

Comment: But is it okay to remove the modulus on $r$ as you did? I mean I was comparing $e^{i(3\tan^{-1}|r|)}=e^{i\pi /4} $?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43009/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-zoz).